# POSTGIS Raster - Merge polygon onto raster

Tags: postgis, raster

I have two tables, SCHEDULE contains polygon geometries and RASTER contains raster tiles

I want to take a polygon from the SCHEDULE table and overlay it on top of a set of RASTER tiles that intersect its bounding box.

I have got this far:-

```
WITH schedule AS (
        -- SELECT A SCHEDULE GEOMETRY AND CREATE A buffer around it 
        SELECT ST_SetSrid(ST_Boundary(ST_Expand(wkb_geometry, 500)),27700) as buffer, wkb_geometry as wkb_geometry, streetward from schedule where schedule_id = 1532952
    ),
    --MERGE THE SCHEDULE GEOMETRY WITH THE BUFFER
    expanded_schedule AS (

        SELECT ST_Union(wkb_geometry, buffer) as wkb_geometry FROM schedule
    ),
    raster_map as (
        --UNION ALL OF THE RASTERS IN RASTER TO COVER BUFFER
        SELECT ST_Union(rast) as rast from RASTER,schedule where ST_Boundary(wkb_geometry)::BOX2d  && rast

    ),
    raster_geom AS (
        --MAKE A RASTER FROM THE GEOMETRY
         SELECT ST_SetBandNoDAtaVAlue(

                ST_ColorMap(
                    ST_AsRaster(wkb_geometry, --SCHEDULE GEOMETRY
                            rast,            --reference raster
                            ARRAY['8BUI','8BUI','8BUI'],         --pixeltype
                            ARRAY[118,118,118],          --data value
                            ARRAY[100,100,100]           --no data value
                            ), 
                    1, '118 1 1 1 1
                        100 254 254 254 254')
            ,100)
         --SELECT ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry, 50), rast,ARRAY['8BUI'], ARRAY[118])
         as rast FROM  expanded_schedule,raster_map

    ) , 
    raster_union AS (
        SELECT rast FROM raster_geom
        UNION
        SELECT rast FROM raster_map
    )
    SELECT ST_AsPng(ST_Union(rast)) FROM raster_union
```

My problem is that this creates an image that looks like the following:-
[image: Output image]

The SCHEDULE geometry area has worked fine, but the bounding box area has masked out the map tiles below. I do not really understand why? I suspect that the buffer geometry is "filled in" as far as postgis is concerned. What am I doing wrong, or should I follow another strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I cracked this in the end but it is not idea.

I removed the ST_Colorband call and now the rasters merge as they should using the colorband of the RASTER raster:-

```
raster_geom AS (

         SELECT ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry,5),       --SCHEDULE GEOMETRY
                            rast,            --reference raster
                            ARRAY['8BUI','8BUI','8BUI'], --pixeltype
                            ARRAY[24,24,24],             --data value
                            ARRAY[0,0,0]             --no data value
                            )--, 

         as rast FROM  schedule,raster_map

    )
```

But it means that I cannot set transparency values which is a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an image that shows if a property on an RGB raster. Your solution helped me a lot!

Pay attention that I used the **Alpha** of RGBA to set the transparency of where I didn't want to show...
You can use this feature to give a certain opacity to the elements you want to show on your map.

I also used ST_Boundary to use only the edges of the geometry.

**Here are my adjustments:**

```
with
--Get the geometry I want to show on the raster
geom as (
    select ST_Union(geom) as geom from public.vector_900aa100_0f94_4542_b23b_b51695df9696
),
--Create an envelope some distance from the geometry
envelope as (
    select ST_Expand(st_envelope(geom), 1000) as envelope_geom, geom from geom
),
--Cut raster and color it
raster_map as (
    SELECT ST_Union(rast) as rast from public.raster_rgb_2020, envelope where ST_Boundary(envelope_geom)::BOX2d  && rast
),
--Creates raster based on geometry
raster_geom as (
     SELECT ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Boundary(geom),35, 'endcap=square join=round'),       --SCHEDULE GEOMETRY
                            rast,            --reference raster
                            ARRAY['8BUI','8BUI','8BUI'], --pixeltype
                            ARRAY[200,10,10,255],          --data value
                            ARRAY[0,0,0,0]               --no data value
                            ) as rast FROM  envelope, raster_map
), 
raster_union AS (
        SELECT rast FROM raster_geom
        UNION
        SELECT rast FROM raster_map
)
SELECT ST_AsPng(ST_Union(rast)) FROM raster_union;
```